# Ошибка в VBS скрипте: Недопустимо использование скобок при вызове процедуры sub

Tags: vbscript, visual-basic

```
Dim WshShell 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set WshProEnv = WshShell.Environment("SYSTEM") 
SysInfo = WshProEnv.Item("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")

If SysInfo = "x86" Then
  WshShell.Run("notepad.exe", 0) 
Else
  WshShell.Run("notepad.exe", 1)
End If
```

Пишет ошибку:

> Недопустимо использование скобок при вызове процедуры sub.

В чем причина?

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky, в использовании WshShell.Run "program.exe" не надо ставить скобки

Answer (score 1):

При использовании `WshShell.Run "program.exe"` (вообще, при вызове процедур) не надо ставить скобки вокруг аргументов:

```
Dim WshShell 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set WshProEnv = WshShell.Environment("SYSTEM") 
SysInfo = WshProEnv.Item("PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE")    

If SysInfo = "x86" Then
      WshShell.Run "notepad.exe",0
Else
      WshShell.Run "notepad.exe",1
End If
```